# How to setup Dev Test Prod AWS ENVs same Organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I am using the IAM role to switch between AWS environments. 
I have 3 assumed roles those match with 3 environments: Dev, Test, Prod. 
Those assumed roles have the same permission such as EC2, S3, ... 
So how I can limit users who trust the dev, test roles cannot touch Prod role via IAM Policy? I try to use the tags of the services to limit. 
Is it the best way to do? Do you have any best practices on this?

```
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "aws:Environment": [
                    "dev",
                ]
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/organizing-your-aws-environment/basic-organization.html see if this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using tags is an acceptable way of doing this.

---

You can also make use of wildcards in resource names to limit the users.

For example, if you include the env terms like "Prod" and "Dev" in all your resources, you can create policies including those terms.

This could be a policy for a Dev role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    [
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": "dynamodb:*",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:account-id:*Dev*"
    ],
    [
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Action": "dynamodb:*",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:account-id:*Prod*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html#reference_policies_elements_resource_wildcards

Comment: Thank you!
This is a good idea, let me try!